# Arduino replace code

Tags: gps, arduino

I'm very new to Arduino and C programming.

I'm making a GPS speedo and I'm trying to read in some serial, store a value from a substring and echo it back via serial.

At the moment I'm having problems storing the substring.

I've gotten to the point where I'm able to get some data between `<` and `>`.
But the data doesn't come in like that.  It's a NMEA data stream and the data I want is between `,N,` and `,K,`.

So I've been trying to replace `,N,` with `<`   and `,K,` with `>` .

Just can't get it to work.  I get `error: request for member 'replace' in 'c', which is of non-class type 'char'`

Here's my code so far....

```cpp
int indata = 0;
int scrubdata = 0;
char inString[32];
int stringPos = 0;
boolean startRead = false; // is reading?

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(4800);
}

void loop() {
  String pageValue = readPage();
  Serial.print(pageValue);
}

String readPage(){
  //read the page, and capture & return everything between '<' and '>'

  stringPos = 0;
  memset( &inString, 0, 32 ); //clear inString memory

  while(true){
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {

      char c = Serial.read();
      c.replace(",N,", "<");
      c.replace(",K,", ">");

      if (c == '<' ) { //'<' is our begining character
        startRead = true; //Ready to start reading the part 
      }
      else if(startRead){

        if(c != '>'){ //'>' is our ending character
          inString[stringPos] = c;
          stringPos ++;
        }
        else{
          //got what we need here! We can disconnect now
          startRead = false;
          return inString;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A GPS speedo!?!?  That doesn't sound comfortable at all!

Answer (score 2):

### By Default:

[`Serial.read()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) returns an `int` if you must process the data this way, try casting it to `char` with:

```cpp
 char c = (char) Serial.read();
```

### Another way to do this:

Would be to seek your beginning string (discarding un-needed data) using [`Serial.find()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Find) then reading data until you met your end character "**,K,**" with [`Serial.readBytesUntil()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytesUntil)

Something like this would work quite well:

```cpp
char inData[64];         //adjust for your data size
Serial.setTimeout(2000); //Defaults to 1000 msecs set if necessary
Serial.find(",N,");      //Start of Data
int bRead = Serial.readBytesUntil(",K,", inData, 64);  //Read until end of data
inData[bRead] = 0x00;    //Zero terminate if using this as a string
return inData;
```